# Python translating nucleotide to amino acid

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I have a function which doesn't work. I have to translate nucleotides sequence from .txt file into amino acids comparing string to dictionary. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this? The output shows only string from .txt file and it's supoosed to be amino acids sequence from this file.

```
f = open('hemoglobin.txt', 'r')
sequence = f.readline()
while sequence:
    sequence = sequence.rstrip()
    print(sequence)
    sequence = f.readline()

gencode = { 'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W' }

def translate(sequence):
    for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3):
        codon = str(sequence[i])
        if codon == gencode['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']:
            print('STOP')
            break
        elif codon == gencode[key]:
            print(gencode[value])
    return()
```

Comment: I suspect that this line `for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3):` isn't doing what you want it to. I imagine you want something more like `for i1, i2 in zip(range(0, len(sequence), 3), range(3, len(sequence), 3)):` followed by `codon = str(sequence[slice(i1, i2)]`

Comment: [`biopython`](https://biopython.org) has all of this and a whole lot more built-in, so you don't have to roll your own.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I suggest taking what you have put up here as a question, format it as a module, and work on debugging it. This is what anyone trying to answer your question would do.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `translate()` function.

```
while sequence:
    sequence = sequence.rstrip()
    translate(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if codon == gencode['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']:
```

to:

```
if codon in ['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']:
```